# transparency turns all objects transparent

Tags: css

Wasn't sure, how to name this question, but, I've ran into a problem (minor, but still), I have a main div container, which is basically a white text box, that is 92% opaque:

```
     -ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=92)";
filter: alpha(opacity=92);
opacity:.92;
```

This works fine, however, on some pages I have a Jplayer audio player and that turns 92% transparent too. Does anyone know a way where I can still have the transparency, but keep objects inside the main div container fully opaque?

Comment: you can set a transparent background-color of an object, but you can not have cildren having a higher opacity than it's parent item.

Comment: Please, post the DIV section and the CSS code including the name and brackets so we can help you faster.

Comment: Post your HTML code. And to fix this you need to have "the full opacity" elements outside the element having the filter added to it, or set filter to only the inner that should have it.

Comment: I just used background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.92); as suggested by thesublimeobject and it has done the trick! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.92);

When you use the background property it only applies the alpha (the last value, opacity) to the background itself. Use this instead of the ms-filter as it works across all **modern browsers.

Comment: No, it does not work cross browser. IE8 does not support rgba()

Comment: except ie {8,7,6,5.5}.

Comment: The issue is though, I am using a gradient background colour

Comment: I guess I could try this one instead though, since the gradient isn't too noticeable with the transparency on

Comment: You could just add an image for ie 8 and below using.

Comment: IE 8 is a problem, true, but my site is only going to be used on Chrome, mostly, very unlikely a randomer will stumble across and try to use it on IE 8

Comment: You can always set some kind of other fallback for IE8 if you're concerned about it, but you're right, a high percentage of your traffic will be IE9+, Chrome, Firefox, Safari, Opera.

Comment: I can nearly guarantee that my traffic will be Chrome only, due to the website purpose and audience, especially since I know personally most of the users, however, I think an image fallback for IE 8 sounds a good idea, like Bento said

Answer (score 1):

**Use This CSS-**

```
#div{
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.92);
}
```

**Then Use this script for browser compatibility in IE.**

```
<!--[if IE]>
   <style type="text/css">
       .color-block { 
           background:transparent;
           filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#50990000,endColorstr=#50990000);
           zoom: 1;
       } 
    </style>
<![endif]-->
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#parent{
    -ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=92)";
}
#parent>*{
    -ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=100)";
}
```

This'll make the parent's alpha 92% and it's children 100%. But I can't remember if this sets the Opacity of the element or the alpha? Because if it sets the opacity of the element. Every element within the parent will also be affected. Another way would be to use an background image, selecting ie 8 and below to use an alternative method or some very awkward positioning.

Comment: Did you try this yourself? .. Because if I'm not wrong this doesn't work on IE6/7/8

Comment: Thanks, I used the RGB option and it worked fine. My main idea was to have a gradient background, but since it's transparent, I don't mind too much :P

Comment: Check "WebDevRon"'s solution. It's good and will fix IE too.

Comment: @PellePenna that's the way I was thinking. Been awhile since I did anything for IE! Didn't think this would've worked I just remember doing it, my bad!